# Spring - No Data when result Less than the size of the page -

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In have JPARepository and I create a method to get data by KeyWord:

That is my interface:

```
@Query(value="select p from Poeple p where name like :x")
public Page<Poeple> searchByMc(@Param( value = "x")String mc, Pageable pageable );
```

In my Service I receive Request and call this method like that:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/poeples", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Poeple> listPoeples(@RequestParam(name="mc") String mc, @RequestParam(name="page", defaultValue="0" ) int page, @RequestParam(name="size", defaultValue="5" )int size){
    mc = "%"+ mc + "%";
    return poepleRepository.searchByMc(mc, new PageRequest(page, size,new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name"))); 
}
```

My problem is that when i have just one or two result my Response content the TotalContent But the content array don't have any data.

I call this Class from my Angular App, looked like that :

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('PoepleController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.mc = '';
  $scope.poeples = [];
  $scope.page=1;
  $scope.size=10;

  $scope.SearchPoeple = function(){
      $http.get("http://localhost:8080/poeples?page="+ $scope.page+"&size="+$scope.size+"&mc="+$scope.mc)
      .then(function(data){
          $scope.poeples = data.data.content;
      }, function(err){
          console.log(err);
      });
  }

});
```

That is my response:

```
{content: [], last: true, totalPages: 1, totalElements: 3, size: 10, number: 1, first: false,…}
content
:
[]
first
:
false
last
:
true
number
:
1
numberOfElements
:
0
size
:
10
sort
:
[{direction: "ASC", property: "name", ignoreCase: false, nullHandling: "NATIVE", ascending: true,…}]
totalElements
:
3
totalPages
:
1
```

Like you can see I have 3result but the content array is empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I let the question because I think that some beginner like me can make the mistake:

The first page is the page 0

Like we can see in my response I had result `first : false`

Because We have to correct in the Angular Code

```
$scope.page = 0
```

I hope this can help!

Comment: Good to know that you have answered it. By the way, you can initialize Pageable in controller like below

 @RequestMapping(value="/poeples", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Poeple> listPoeples(@RequestParam(name="mc") String mc, Pageable pageable){
    mc = "%"+ mc + "%";
    return poepleRepository.searchByMc(mc, pageable); 
}